# JPanel notified by LayoutManager when resized

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have a class `MyPanel` that extends `JPanel`.
`MyPanel` is a child panel: his size is dinamically calculated by the `LayoutManager` of his parent.
**The problem is that I need `MyPanel` to be notified as soon as the `LayoutManager` of his parent calculates his size.**
It needs to be notified because I need to initialize some variables according to the panel's size.
If I call `getSize()` in the MyPanel constructor i get (0,0) because the panel is not "ready".
When should i call `getSize()`?
I'd like to have something like this:

```
/** Lays out the panel and sets his size according to his layout */
@Override
public void onReady() {
    System.out.println(getSize()); //output is (0,0);
    super.onReady();
    System.out.println(getSize()); //output is (600,500);
    //here i can initialize my variables
}
```

Is there something similar? Maybe `doLayout()`?
The only way i could find is calling `getSize()` in the `paintComponent()` method... it surely works because the panel is surely displayed when `paintComponent()` is called but I can't do this because i need to initialize some variables as soon as i know the panel size... but only once! `paintComponent()` will be called several times...

Comment: *"The problem is that I need MyPanel to be notified as soon as the LayoutManager of his parent calculates his size."*  Why?  What extra ability does that provide for your application?  What does it achieve?

Comment: It's because I need to initialize some variables according to the panel's size

Comment: If it is unresizable, why not set a `preferredSize()` and `pack()` the frame and rest the frame not resizable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [`ComponentListener.componentResized()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29).

Comment: -1: Hard, broken link. I suggest including some relevant quotes... for now, your answer is useless.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare feel free to correct the link if it is now broken (done it now). Downvoting is quite lame, to be honest.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to use a ComponentListener.

See ComponentListener.componentResized(ComponentEvent)